# Definitive Wordpress folder permissions

Tags: wordpress

I can't seem to find this anywhere. Does anyone know where there is a definitive list of Windows/Linux permissions for noobs for all folders in Wordpress? I'm ok with chmodding, chowning and chgrouping, I just don't seem to be able to make it possible for users to upload files (images are ok for some reason) to a server. I've tried on both Windows and Linux, with Linux being my preferred platform, but to no avail.

Just once and for all I'd like to know what I should do here! Is there a list out there??!

Comment: Exact duplicate: [What is true chmod for WordPress?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/2743)

Comment: Your best bet is to make all folders writable for the www-user / group. I dont prefere to plain set 666 and 777.

Comment: Thanks for that @DannyBeckett, I was sure there had to be another post, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @DanFromGermany 777 sounds VERY insecure. Not sure I'll be doing that, thanks for the contrib though!

Comment: I did not suggest you to use 777. I suggested you to 700 folders and 600 files.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it (change the stuff within brackets to your environment:)

```
$ cd [wordpress_install_folder]
$ chown -R [webuser]:[mygroup] *
$ chmod -R g+w *
$ chown root:root wp-config.php
$ chmod 644 wp-config.php
```

Comment: I've been told to 755 all the things. I also found this: http://www.mintblogger.com/2009/08/how-to-secure-your-wordpress.html which mentions 644 on files and 755 on folders. Is that good advice?

Answer (score 1):

The following files need to be writable:

```
/sitemap.*         (dependes)
/.htaccess
/wp-config.php
/wp-content/       (recursively)
```

if you want to allow wordpress updates, simply set `./` to be writable

Now if you're asking whom to grant write/execute permission, it depends on your server config,
on the httpd user/group and the file's owner.
You should allow `600` for files and `700` for directories. if it doesnt work, include group permission `660` and `770`. Some servers need `666` and `777` tho but you might have a chrooted environment and it would not even matter for other vhosts / shares which permission, because you can't break out of the chroot.

Wordpress uses the httpd user to write, but you probably use the ftp user to write.
It's just all about getting to know who does what, and that this is not the same on all servers.

if the files belong to the FTP user but the www user is in the assigned group =>
660 / 770

if the files belong to the www user but the ftp user is in the assigned group => 660 / 770

if ftp and www are the same user => 600 / 700

if at least 1 of the two users is not in the files group AND not the owner => 666 and 777

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, change your file and folder ownership to your web server user (apache, nginx, www-data, etc)

You can do this using:

```
cd /path/to/wordpress/
chown -R apache *
chgrp -R apache *
```

Then change your file and directory permissions (as recommended by the Wordpress Codex). The first command will change your directory permissions. The second command changes your file permissions. The `.` indicates that it will change everything from the current directory.

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

If you want to read more about securing your Wordpress installation see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_permissions

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set permissions for WordPress if you are using Linux Ubuntu is to *give ownership of the directory to the apache user*:

```
sudo chown username:www-data /path/to/wordpress -R 
sudo chmod g+w /path/to/wordpress -R
```

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: The Wordpress developers disagree. 
"All files should be owned by your user account, and should be writable by you. Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be writable by the web server, if your hosting set up requires it, that may mean those files need to be group-owned by the user account used by the web server process."

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/security/hardening/#file-permissions

Comment: See also:
"Typically, all files should be owned by your user (ftp) account on your web server, and should be writable by that account. On shared hosts, files should never be owned by the webserver process itself (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody user)."

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/server/file-permissions/